# Can someone explain the output of this program written in C

Tags: c, pointers, output

```
int x = 5;

int *p = &x;

printf("%u\t%u\n",&x,p);

printf("%d\n",*(p++));

printf("%d\n",*p);
```

Can someone help me understand the pointer arithmetic?
And what will be the output?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please copy-paste code (or any text really) as *text* into your questions.

Comment: To print a pointer with `printf` you need to use `%p`. And you need to cast the pointer to `void *`. Mismatching format specifier and argument type leads to *undefined behavior*. So `printf("%u\t%u\n",&x,ptr);` should be `printf("%%p\t%p\n", (void *) &x, (void *) ptr);`

Comment: Please be more specific about what you don't understand. How to use printf, how pointers work, how de-referencing pointers work, how the ++ operators work, how pointer arithmetic works. Which is the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you increased `ptr`, it's no longer pointing anywhere valid. Dereferencing the pointer with `*ptr` leads to *undefined behavior*.

It might be simpler to understand if you consider `&x` to be an array of a single element, and the initialization of `p` (or `ptr`, whichever you really picked) makes `p` point to the first (and only) element of that array. By increasing `p` it will be pointing *out of bounds* of that single-element array.

---

To visualize it, lets draw it out...

First you have

```
int x = 5;
```

which can be drawn as

```
+-------+
| x (5) |
+-------+
```

Now we define and initialize the pointer to that:

```
int *p = &x;
```

So now it will look like this:

```
+-------+
| x (5) |
+-------+
 ^
 |
+---+
| p |
+---+
```

The variable `p` is *pointing* to the variable `x` (the "up-arrow" in the illustration above).

If you then increase the pointer:

```
p++;
```

then it will look like this:

```
+-------+----
| x (5) | ???
+-------+----
         ^
         |
        +---+
        | p |
        +---+
```

The pointer is no longer pointing to `x`. What it points to is unknown, and the value at that location is also unknown.

So to answer the question about what is printed and why, we can't say.

Undefined behavior (UB for short) often isn't predicable, and there might be no way to tell what will happen.